# How to pass multiple Types that implement the same interface?

Tags: java, generics, pecs

Firstly apologies about the not so great title, I am new to Java and wasn't sure how to title this.

I have a interface class "TestInterface":

```
ublic interface TestInterface {

    String getForename();

    void setForename(String forename);

    String getSurname();

    void setSurname(String surname);
}
```

"TestImpl" implements "TestInterface":

```
public class TestImpl implements TestInterface{

    private String forename;

    private String surname;

    @Override
    public String getForename() {
        return forename;
    }

    public void setForename(String forename) {
        this.forename = forename;
    }

    @Override
    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }
}
```

Then I have a call called "ExtendTest" which extends "TestImpl":

```
public class ExtendTest extends TestImpl{

    private String firstLineAddress;

    public String getFirstLineAddress() {
        return firstLineAddress;
    }

    public void setFirstLineAddress(String firstLineAddress) {
        this.firstLineAddress = firstLineAddress;
    }
}
```

I then have this "Entity" class:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Entity {

    private List<TestInterface> testInterfaces;

    private List<ExtendTest> extendTests;

    public List<TestInterface> getTestInterfaces() {
        return testInterfaces;
    }

    public void setTestInterfaces(List<TestInterface> testInterfaces) {
        this.testInterfaces = testInterfaces;
    }

    public List<ExtendTest> getExtendTests() {
        return extendTests;
    }

    public void setExtendTests(List<ExtendTest> extendTests) {
        this.extendTests = extendTests;
    }
}
```

and finally this "DoStuff" class where the dostuff method accepts a parameter of type List

```
import java.util.List;

public class DoStuff {

    public void doStuff(List<TestInterface> testData) {

    }
}
```

I try to test this like so:

```
public class Main {


        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Hello, World!");

            DoStuff doStuff = new DoStuff();


            Entity entity = new Entity();

            // Works
            doStuff.doStuff(entity.getTestInterfaces());

            // Does not work
            doStuff.doStuff(entity.getExtendTests());

        }
}
```

However where the comment is "Does not work" their is an error

```
Required type:
List<TestInterface>
Provided:
List<ExtendTest>
```

My question is how do I make it so that I can pass it in. My understanding was that becase they all implement TestInterface that it would work but I think I am wrong with this.

Thanks for any help and learnings here :)

Comment: The doStuff method should be `public void doStuff(List<? extends TestInterface> testData) {`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've run afoul of [PECS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super). I recommend reading the linked answer for a more detailed explanation, but here's the bits specific to your use case.

When you have a generic type (`List`, in your case), if you only *read* from it, you should write `List<? extends MyInterface>`. If you only *write* to it, you should write `List<? super MyInterface>`. If you do both, then you want `List<MyInterface>`. Why do we do this? Well, look at your code.

```
public void doStuff(List<TestInterface> testData) { ... }
```

This function takes a `List<TestInterface>`. The [`List` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) has a ton of capability. You can add and remove things to it in addition to just reading from it. And `doStuff` expects a list of `TestInterface`. So it's entirely fair game for the implementation of `doStuff` to do

```
testData.add(new ClassIJustMadeUp());
```

assuming `ClassIJustMadeUp` implements `TestInterface`. So we definitely can't pass this function a `List<ExtendTest>`, since that list type can't contain `ClassIJustMadeUp`.

However, if your function *does* only read from the list and isn't planning to add anything to it, you can write the signature as

```
public void doStuff(List<? extends TestInterface> testData) { ... }
```

and now you can pass a `List` of *any* type which extends `TestInterface`. It's fine to read from this list, since any type which extends `TestInterface` clearly can be upcast safely to `TestInterface`. But if we try to add a list element, that's a compiler error since the list doesn't necessarily support that particular type.